# Can I save json data in a .js page instead of a .json file

Tags: javascript, json

We are building a static app of sorts where a user can publish static pages from our site, download them and install them on their own web server. In order to do this we are relying on JSON data which will be stored in json files. My concern is that we have no way of controlling their servers and I am unclear if their servers will support .json file mime/types.

Can we just save the json data in a .js file, instead to avoid this potential problem?

Comment: Yes why not? JSON is a part of JavaScript

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Eh, no. JSON is a object notation based on JavaScript.

Comment: That makes the notation valid enough to be placed in a `.js` file :)

Comment: That's true, indeed. I'm just nitpicking ;-)

Comment: to make it a valid js yo need to assign it to a variable, can be global or part of a module

Comment: @Cerbrus I read nitpicking and had to step in. JSON is not 100% compatible with JavaScript http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Just save it as a variable in JS.

```
var myJsonData = {
    "thing": true,
    "otherThing:" 4
    "fancyArray":[
        "hello",
        "hi",
        "greetings"
    ]
};
```